# symfony3 twig and show session array

Tags: php, session, twig, symfony

I have array in session, but I can't show them. 
My code:
Controller:

```
  $game = $request->query->get('game');
  $type = $request->query->get('type');
  $odd = $request->query->get('odd');

  $kupon = array(
                 'game' => $game,
                 'type' => $type,
                 'odd' => $odd,
               );

   $this->get('session')->set('kupon', $kupon);
```

Where 'game' is for example: 'Arsenal - Chelsea', 'type' is number like 1, and odd is float number like '2.2'.

Twig file:

```
{% if app.session.get('kupon') is not null %}
<table>
{% for kupon in session %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ kupon.game }}</td>
      <td>{{ kupon.type }}</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

And everything ok, but when I try log in and show data session, I have this error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("game") on a string variable ("PNdjNUeuZ_d5uJlm1VG7zPZhp2Vb4CY3nDf93vAQ574") in baw\kupon.html.twig at line 13.

This variable is from session after log in, I checked dump information about it:

```
array(3) { 
["_csrf/login"]=> string(43) "PNdjNUeuZ_d5uJlm1VG7zPZhp2Vb4CY3nDf93vAQ574" ["login"]=> string(4) "test" 
["kupon"]=> array(3) { ["game"]=> string(31) "Arsenal Londyn - Chelsea Londyn" ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["odd"]=> string(3) "2.2" } }
```

And now I haven't any idea to fix this.

Comment: so are you using symfony2 or 3? use the correct tags please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% for kupon in session %}` will not loop over `app.session.get('kupon')`

what you want to do is:

```
{% for kupon in app.session.get('kupon') %}
```

But looking at you dumped data, `app.session.get('kupon')` is just a single dataset, so you cant even loop that (with desired results)...

it will be just:

```
{{ app.session.get('kupon').game }}
```

extra explanations about your data: you have this in you session:

```
"kupon" => [
    "game" => ...
    "type" => ...
    ...
]
```

to be able to loop over these, you need to make a collection of your data types:

```
"kupon" => [
    [
        "game" => ...
        "type" => ...
        ...
    ],
    [
        "game" => ...
        "type" => ...
        ...
    ],
    ....
]
```

Comment: ok, I changed it, but now everything is x3. Everything data with array I must have separately, for example: `<td>name</td><td>surname</td>`, now I have something like that: `<td>name surname</td> <td>name surname</td>`. I change to this: `{% for kupon in app.session.get('kupon') %}` and this: `<td>{{ app.session.get('kupon').game }}</td>`. I tried even `kupon.game` or something, but I had error: _"Impossible to access an attribute ("game") on a string variable ("Arsenal Londyn - Chelsea Londyn") in baw\kupon.html.twig at line 13."_

Comment: Did you tried `{{ app.session.get('kupon').game }}` ?

Comment: as I said, you can not put this in a loop, because the data is not a collection... you just have one "instance" of a "kupon"; Ive updated my answer with a clear example

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
{% if app.session.get('kupon') is not null %}
  {% set kupon = app.session.get('kupon') %}
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ kupon.game }}</td>
        <td>{{ kupon.type }}</td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
{% endif %}
```